# Decide When to Use ConfigureAwait(false)

Tags: c#, async-await

If the statements in the call graph after "await" point does not access any object whose type is not derived from System.Windows.UIElement class, can we say that the developer safely use ConfigureAwait(false) for Windows Mobile apps?

What kind of statements must have been executed on UI thread besides updating GUI elements?

Answer (score 13):

Any code that directly (or indirectly) manipulates UI elements should be run in the UI context. Usually, this just includes direct manipulation and updating ViewModels.

In all other situations, you should use `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

Comment: To [quote yourself](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html): *A good rule of thumb is to use `ConfigureAwait(false)` unless you know you* do *need the context.*

Comment: I want to implement a static analysis to find out the cases where I don't need the context.

Would it be safe if I implement in the way above?

Comment: @TomK.: If you implement your static analysis to include any code that raises an event when any subscription of that event may update a UI element, then that should be sufficient.

Comment: What benefit does ConfigureAwait(false) provide when it can be used?

Comment: @OwenJohnson: Efficiency. Specifically, your code doesn't interrupt the UI thread if it doesn't have to.